# How to define color of intersection in a Venn diagram?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I found many resources on how to draw Venn diagrams in R. [Stack Overflow has a lot of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/venn-diagram+r). However, I still can't draw my diagrams the way I want. Take the following code as an example:

```
library("VennDiagram")

A <- 1:4
B <- 3:6
d <- list(A, B)

vp <- venn.diagram(d, fill = c("white", "white"), alpha = 1, filename = NULL, 
  category.names=c("A", "B"))
grid.draw(vp)
```

[image]

I want the intersection between the sets to be red. However, if I change any of the white colors to red, I get the following:

```
vp_red <- venn.diagram(d, fill = c("red", "white"), alpha = 1, filename = NULL, 
  category.names=c("A", "B"))
grid.draw(vp_red)
```

[image]

That's not quite what I want. I want only the intersection to be red. If I change the alpha, this is what I get:

```
vp_alpha <- venn.diagram(d, fill = c("red", "white"), alpha = 0.5, filename = NULL, 
  category.names=c("A", "B"))
grid.draw(vp_alpha)
```

[image]

Now I have pink in my intersection. This is not what I want as well. What I want is something like this [image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)):

[image]

How can I do this? Maybe `VennDiagram` package can't do it and I need some other package, but I've been testing different ways to do it, and I'm not being able to find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will show two different possibilities. In the first example, `polyclip::polyclip` is used to get the intersection. In the second example, circles are converted to `sp::SpatialPolygons` and we get the intersection using `rgeos::gIntersection`. Then we re-plot the circles and fill the intersecting area.

---

The resulting object when using `venn.diagram` is

> "of class `gList` containing the `grid` objects that make up the diagram"

Thus, in both cases we can grab relevant data from "vp". First, check the `str`ucture and list the `grobs` of the object:

```
str(vp)
grid.ls()
# GRID.polygon.234
# GRID.polygon.235
# GRID.polygon.236 <~~ these are the empty circles
# GRID.polygon.237 <~~ $ col : chr "black"; $ fill: chr "transparent"
# GRID.text.238 <~~ labels
# GRID.text.239
# GRID.text.240
# GRID.text.241
# GRID.text.242
```

---

### 1. `polyclip`

Grab x- and y-values, and put them in the format required for `polyclip`:

```
A <- list(list(x = as.vector(vp[[3]][[1]]), y = as.vector(vp[[3]][[2]])))
B <- list(list(x = as.vector(vp[[4]][[1]]), y = as.vector(vp[[4]][[2]])))
```

Find intersection:

```
library(polyclip)
AintB <- polyclip(A, B)
```

Grab labels:

```
ix <- sapply(vp, function(x) grepl("text", x$name, fixed = TRUE))
labs <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(vp[ix], `[`, c("x", "y", "label")))
```

Plot it!

```
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
polygon(A[[1]])
polygon(B[[1]])
polygon(AintB[[1]], col = "red")
text(x = labs$x, y = labs$y, labels = labs$label)
```

[image]

---

### 2. `SpatialPolygons` and `gIntersection`

Grab the coordinates of the circles:

```
# grab x- and y-values from first circle
x1 <- vp[[3]][["x"]]
y1 <- vp[[3]][["y"]]

# grab x- and y-values from second circle
x2 <- vp[[4]][["x"]]
y2 <- vp[[4]][["y"]]
```

Convert points to `SpatialPolygons` and find their intersection:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
p1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x1, y1))), ID = 1))) 
p2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x2, y2))), ID = 2))) 

ip <- gIntersection(p1, p2)
```

Plot it!

```
# plot circles 
plot(p1, xlim = range(c(x1, x2)), ylim = range(c(y1, y2))) 
plot(p2, add = TRUE) 

# plot intersection
plot(ip, add = TRUE, col = "red") 

# add labels (see above)
text(x = labs$x, y = labs$y, labels = labs$label)
```

[image]

---

I'm quite sure you could work directly on the `grobs` using clipping functions in `grid` or `gridSVG` package.

Comment: No. You may find something useful in [plot.euler.R](https://github.com/jolars/eulerr/blob/master/R/plot.euler.R).

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy in eulerr R package

```
library(eulerr)
plot(euler(c("A"=5,"B"=4,"A&B"=2)),quantities = TRUE,fills=c("white","white","red"))
```

[euler set colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHU0m.png)