# How to make each part of overlap circles to be different color in R code?

Tags: r, shiny

I don't want to change the transparency of circles, but I want to let each part of the graph to be different colors. For example, circle A is red and circle B is yellow. Then the intersecting part is orange. How can I do that in R?

## ui

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Probability"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

  h4(p("Choose radiuses of the circle and see change of probability")),

  sliderInput("radius",
              "Radius 1",
              min = 0,
              max = 1,
              value = 0.5),
  sliderInput("radius2",
              "Radius 2",
              min = 0,
              max = 1,
              value = 0.5),
  sliderInput("radius3",
              "Radius 3",
              min = 0,
              max = 1,
              value = 0.5) 
),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)
  )
))
```

## server

```
library(shiny)
library(plotrix)
library(grid)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    isolate({
      plot(c(-2,2),c(-2,2), type = 'n')

    })

    col1 <- rgb(red = .0, green = 0, blue = 0.8, alpha = 0.8)
    col2 <- rgb(red = .9, green = 0.9, blue = 0, alpha = 0.8)
    col3 <- rgb(red = 0.8, green = 0, blue = 0.5, alpha = 0.8)
    draw.circle(-0.5,0,input$radius,col=col1)
    draw.circle(0.5,0,input$radius2,col=col2)
    draw.circle(0,-1,input$radius3,col=col3)

  },width=500,height = 500)

})
```

Comment: Check out [this approach](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/321733.html).

Comment: I have previously tried two different alternatives here: [How to define color of intersection in a Venn diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963293/how-to-define-color-of-intersection-in-a-venn-diagram/43965223#43965223)

Comment: You may consider to make your question more succint by removing the (IMHO) peripheral `shiny` parts.