# Coloring the overlap of plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to visualize the overlap of multiple shapes in R and highlight the overlap graphically.

I have managed to draw circles into a plot, however I am not clear if these are actually objects I can then use further or if they are only drawn objects

This draws circles...

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="Niche dimension 1", ylab="Niche dimension 2", main="Niche properties", xlim=c(0,20), ylim=c(0,20))
sp1<-draw.circle(10,10,3, border="darkgreen", lwd=2,col="darkgreen", density=20, angle=90)
sp2<-draw.circle(8,8,2, border="red", lwd=2, col="red", density=20, angle=180)
legend(15,3, legend=c("species 1", "species 2", "niche overlap"), fill=c("darkgreen","red",), cex=0.6)
```

Now I would expect some package to be able to intersect the 2 circles into an object which I could then plot and color differently. However I have yet to find one that actually works...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531124/how-to-make-each-part-of-overlap-circles-to-be-different-color-in-r-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use spatial functions to do the work of creating the circles as objects then continue to use a spatial approach to find intersections and so on for plotting.

Here's an example.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
point1 = data.frame(x=1,y=1)
coordinates(point1) = ~ x + y
circle1 = gBuffer(point1, width = 10)
point2 = data.frame(x=3,y=3)
coordinates(point2) = ~ x + y
circle2 = gBuffer(point2, width = 10)

overlap = gIntersection(circle1, circle2)
circle1Only = gDifference(circle1, circle2)
circle2Only = gDifference(circle2, circle1)
all = gUnion(circle1, circle2)

plot(all) # make sure all pieces are included
plot(circle1Only, col = 'red', add = T)
plot(circle2Only, col = 'blue', add=T)
plot(overlap, col = 'green', add= T)
```

[image]

Comment: how do I get "real-looking" circles and not polygons?

Comment: The `gBuffer` function has a parameter `quadsegs` that controls the number of segments to use. Set this to a large number like 100, to get a smoother shape.