# How to draw a venn diagram of two sets, with the intersection colored with blue, rest of the area white and borders with black

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

to draw a venn diagram with colored intersection, legends with border

```
# Draw a Venn diagram
x <- list(A = 1:3, B = 3:5, C = 5:7)
venn(x, col="black", snames = "AB, BC, CD")
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate,  does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963293/how-to-define-color-of-intersection-in-a-venn-diagram/43965223